Modify an API response OWASP Juice Shop (Register as a user with administrator privileges)
OWASP Juice Shop has a challenge to register a user with admin privileges.
To solve the challenge its needed to modify the API Response, I need to change the 'role' from customer to admin, I have seen people using a program to do that, to "Intercept" the response and change it.
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "username": "",
        "role": "customer",
        "deluxeToken": "",
        "lastLoginIp": "0.0.0.0",
        "profileImage": "/assets/public/images/uploads/default.svg",
        "isActive": true,
        "id": 26,
        "email": "12355@123",
        "updatedAt": "2024-07-18T12:18:18.661Z",
        "createdAt": "2024-07-18T12:18:18.661Z",
        "deletedAt": null
    }
}


I have successfully sent a request to the API and have modified the params, copying the payload and changing e-mails or passwords, but I don't know how to intercept and change the response.
payload =  {
  "email": "123552@123",
  "password": "12345",
  "passwordRepeat": "12345",
  "securityQuestion": {
    "id": 6,
    "question": "Paternal grandmother's first name?",
    "createdAt": "2024-07-18T12:03:54.707Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-07-18T12:03:54.707Z"
  },
  "securityAnswer": "dsa"
}

url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/Users'
response = requests.post(url, json=payload)

Is it possible to do that without programs? just using f12 dev tools?
If is not possible, how can I myself write a program to intercept that?
Thanks in advance.

You need to write an HTTP proxy. Creating a simple one in which you hard code the changes you want to make to a request or response should be pretty easy.
You will need to configure your browser to use your proxy, and thats about it. At least for HTTP.
If you need to support HTTPS then it gets harder as you have to create and use your own root CA certificate and trust that in your browser.
It gets harder from there on in - I've been working on ZAP since 2010 and theres still so much more we need to do...
